# Local icon in vuetify button

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have vue project without npm, yarn or smth else. I've just downloaded all vue files local

[image]

and now I want to use my local icon2 in vuetify v-btn as button icon. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<v-btn icon>
  <v-img src="path/to/your/icon.svg" />
</v-btn>
```

As described in [Vuetify's docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/buttons/), since the `v-btn` uses a slot for content, you can put any element you want in that slot.
The `icon` prop simply tells the v-btn to be especially styled for icons (round & flat).

Comment: But in this case, I noticed that the 'v-image' class DIV is put inside the 'v-btn__content' class SPAN. Isn't it very bad practice?